# Why only one arraylist in a class holds variables of all objects?

Tags: java, class, oop, arraylist

I have a problem mentioned in title. I will presenet every step for you to understand what I am trying to do. Firstly, in order to summarize my classes, I showed them below:

```
Classes
|___ Starter.java (main class)
|___ Line.java
|___ CrossSection.java
|___ SectionAssigner.java
```

In my main class, I created ArrayList variables which holds objects from **Line**, **SectionAssigner** and **CrossSection** classes:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
    ArrayList<Line> lineKeeper = new ArrayList<Line>();
    ArrayList<CrossSection> crossSections = new ArrayList<CrossSection>();
    ArrayList<SectionAssigner> sectionAssigners = new ArrayList<SectionAssigner>();
}
```

Constructor of **SectionAssigner** class gets two parameter which are **ArrayList** and **CrossSection**:

```java
public SectionAssigner(ArrayList<Line> lineList, CrossSection crossSection){
    this.lineList = lineList;
    this.crossSection = crossSection;
}
```

In addition, **SectionAssigner** class returns lengths of all lines (**this.linelist**) with the function of **getLinesLength()**:

```java
public ArrayList<Double> getLinesLength(){
    for (int k=0; k<this.lineList.size(); k++) {
        this.returnedIndex.add(this.lineList.get(k).getLength());
    }
    return this.returnedIndex;
}
```

In the below lines of code in my main class, I am asking user to "which lines and cross section do you want to assign to SectionAssigner?", then I am keeping user line selections in **linekeeper** variable and cross section index in **crossSectionIndex** variable. Then, with these datas, I am creating a new variable from **SectionAssigner** which is also inserted to the **sectionAssigners** ArrayList:

```java
sectionAssigners.add(new SectionAssigner(lineKeeper, crossSections.get(crossSectionIndex)));
```

Lastly I am showing user to which lines was assigned which sections:

```java
System.out.println("SectionAssigned" + counter + ": " + sectionAssigners.get(counter).getLinesLength() );
```

These codes and things what I am trying to do may be hard to undestand, so I will illustrate them below with an example:

Lets say user has 6 lines which have index of

```
Line0
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

After that, user want to do cross section assigning like below:

```
SectionAssign0: Line0, Line1
SectionAssign1: Line2, Line3, Line4, Line5
```

So, in the example like above, console should show line0 and line 1 in SectionAssign0; line2, line3, line4, line5 in SectionAssign1. But console shows like below instead of:

```
SectionAssign0: Line0, Line1, Line2, Line3, Line4, Line5
SectionAssign1: Line0, Line1, Line2, Line3, Line4, Line5
```

I dont know usage of ArrayList fully. Does an element of one ArrayList in a class keep all of the objects created from this class? Or are there any fatal mistake that I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does an element of one ArrayList in a class keep all of the objects created from this class?

No, only the ones added too it.

The problem is here:

```
sectionAssigners.add(new SectionAssigner(lineKeeper, crossSections.get(crossSectionIndex)));
```

All of your `sectionAssigners` use the **same** `ArrayList` (`lineKeeper`). If you want them to store things separately, they'll each have to have their *own* `ArrayList` rather than sharing.